# How to install ipopt for python on Windows using Anaconda

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, ipopt

For my current project i needed a solver. My selection fell on IPOPT.

When trying to install IPOPT for Python using Anaconda i stumbled upon multiple problems.

For example:

`conda install ipopt`

installed the ipopt package formally but trying to import it afterwards in Python didn't work.

```
import ipopt
```

failed with:

```
No module named "ipopt".
```

Reading the docs of ipopt, cyipopt and pyipopt didn't bring any clarification.

System:

> Windows 10 64bit, Anaconda 1.9.7, Python 3.7.5 (64bit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what fixed the problem for me and allowed for a clean ipopt installation in a seperate environment:

```
conda create -y -n ipopt_env
conda activate ipopt_env
conda install -y -c pycalphad cyipopt
```

This should install ipopt into your current environment:

```
conda install -y -c pycalphad cyipopt
```

testing:

```
python -c “import ipopt”
```

should not return anything.

Execute the following in python for access to the documentation:

```
import ipopt
help(ipopt)
help(ipopt.problem)
help(ipopt.minimize_ipopt)
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming to this after the answer from @johannes, the pycalphad Anaconda channel is no longer maintaining `ipopt`/`cyipopt` builds for Windows. Since early 2021, [`ipopt`](https://github.com/conda-forge/ipopt-feedstock) and [`cyipopt`](https://github.com/conda-forge/cyipopt-feedstock) [2] are now being distributed by the `conda-forge` channel.

They can be installed using Anaconda by:

`conda install -c conda-forge ipopt cyipopt`

Comment: ran the code through anaconda prompt, still getting the error `ApplicationError: No executable found for solver 'ipopt'` while `import ipopt` doesn't show any error.

Comment: You may want to report that upstream, either at the cyipopt package (https://github.com/mechmotum/cyipopt) or the conda-forge feedstock (https://github.com/conda-forge/cyipopt-feedstock)